# How to make these two elements side by side

Tags: html, css, button, division

I would like to make these two elements or divs align next to each other. Currently this is the website. www.toppertv.org *(the second part is hidden until I figure the code out)

The code is as follows:

```
<div id="social-list" class="text-center">
<h4><b> Connect With us</b></h4>
<ul>
   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TopperTV13" >                                
      <img src="img/facebook-small.png" >
</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com/topper_tv" >                            
      <img src="img/twitter-small.png" >
</a></li>                   
   <li><a href="instagram.com/toppertv" >                              
     <img src="img/instagram-small.png" >
</a></li>               
</ul>
</div>

<div id="btn" class="text-center"><a href="https://www.smartrecruiters.com/toppertv" >                  

<h4>Apply Now</h4>
</a></div>
```

The Css:

```
#social-list h4 ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
float:left;      
}

#social-list ul li {    
display:inline;
}

#social-list ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
padding:0.2em 1em 0.2em 1em;
}

#social-list ul li a img {
width:auto;
}

#btn{
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS in your code.

```
#social-list,
#btn {
  float: left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`div`s are block elements, by default. You have to set the display for your `#social-list` to, probably, `inline-block`.

Comment: If you don't care much for the old web (aka IE's and other non evergreen browsers), a better approach, is to use [flexbox](css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust the width as per your requirement.

```
#social-list
{
    width: 600px;  
    float: left;
}
#btn
{
    width: 300px;  
    float: left;
}
```